# visual basic variable button name

Tags: vb.net

In that

```
Dim btnid As Integer
dgkayitlar.Rows(selectedrow).Cells(4).Value = btnid
Form2.btnOda(btnid).BackColor = Color.Red
```

I can not work like this.

I have buttons names like `btnOda101`, `btnOda201`, `btnOda301`.

I want to use `btnid` instead of 101,102.

how can I do it ?

Comment: You can [edit] your question to provide more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this. You will need to use button names with the format `btnOda_101` the underscore enables the code to split out the id

```
Dim btnId As Integer = 101

'Get list of buttons
Dim buttons = From c In Controls Where TypeOf (c) Is Button Select c

'Find the button with the desired ID
Dim button = (From b In buttons Where b.name.ToString.Split("_")(1) = btnId Select b).FirstOrDefault

'Use that button
Dim myButton As Button = CType(button, Button)
myButton.BackColor = Color.Red
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dictionaries like this

```
public btnOda as Dictionary(Of Integer, Button)

public Sub InitButtons()
    btnOda = new Dictionary(Of Integer, Button)()
    btnOda.add(101, btnOda101)
    btnOda.add(102, btnOda102)
    btnOda.add(301, btnOda301)
    '...

End Sub

public Sub MyFunc()
    Dim btnid As Integer
    btnOda(btnid).BackColor = Color.Red

End Sub
```